# Angular UI-Router, unable to pass the third parameter

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular UI-router for navigation and also passing parameters from view to view, but I am unable to figure out why passing the third parameter in my code fails.
The simplified code below works fine with two parameters, but as soon as I add the third one, then the navigation fails: when I click on the link, simply nothing happens - no errors, when I take the third parameter out - everything works fine. Any help is appreciated.

```
.state('page.details', {
        url: '^/child-page/{id1:int}/{name}',
        views: {
            '@': {
                templateUrl: '/child-page.html',
                controller: 'ChildCtrl'
            }
        }
    })


<a href="#" ui-sref="page.details({id1:5, name:somename})">
```

Now when I add the third parameter, the navigation fails:

```
url: '^/child-page/{id0:int}/{id1:int}/{name}'
<a href="#" ui-sref="page.details({id0:3, id1:5, name:somename})">
```

**EDIT:**
It turned out the problem was a syntax error, but not caused by third parameter itself. In the actual working code there was a left-over quotation mark on one side of the URL in HTML that was misleading the UI router. The router was assuming that the provided URL was valid and was trying to load the resource. Then not finding it, the default view was being loaded instead. Once the quotation mark was taken out, the third parameter started showing up in the child view. Appreciate for having taken a look to help.

Comment: Maybe it conflicts with other state with the same url structure?

Comment: None of the other states has such a structure, they all are with max two parameters...

Comment: do you have a reason for don't use params object in sate? like `params: { 
    id0: null, 
    id1: null,
    name: null
  }` maybe this one can work.

Comment: params: { id0: null, id1: null, name: null } - this too takes to the 'otherwise', meaning that the router cannot identify the URL. I am just puzzled, why with two parameters all works, but three  - does not.

Comment: Maybe you have a rule that add backslash to the url? so perhaps  `'^/child-page/{id0:int}/{id1:int}/{name}/'` will work? How exactly does the WORKING state url looks like? Also, does the state is accessible when you enter the URL directly?

Comment: Alon, thanks for your insight, once I tried to access the URL directly, I started seeing error messages in Firebug - it turned out it was completely unrelated to the third parameter. It actually was my syntax error, a left-over quotation mark that somehow ended up as a part of the URL parameters in HTML, probably when I added the third parameter.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like thismaybe:

```
url: '^/child-page/:id0/:id1/:name'
```

Comment: This syntax bounces to the 'otherwise' state, thanks

Comment: Appreciate everybody's time trying to help.  I added a comment above responding to Alon, It turned out it was my syntax error, a left-over quotation mark in the URL parameters in HTML, that was misleading UI-router.